# Best way to animate scaling and sizing of buttons in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using the code below to animate an intro-animation for buttons in an iOS Swift game. This code is inside of an update function and is the same for a lot of buttons.

```
    if self.creditsButton.size.width < 40 {
        self.creditsButton.size.width += 1
        self.creditsButton.size.height += 1
    }
```

My question is; is there a better (more clean) way to animate scaling/sizes of buttons/menu's?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the button is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` then [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html) enables you to schedule the animation without needing to regularly update, e.g. (apologies for the objective-C):

```
SKAction *scale = [SKAction resizeToWidth:40.0 duration:0.4];
[spriteNode runAction:scale];
```

Comment: Can I run that action on multiple `SKSpriteNodes`?

Comment: You can enumerate through an array of `SKSpriteNodes` creating and running an `SKAction` for each.